# If X and Y are independent exponential random variables with respective parameters λ1 and λ2, how do I find the distribution of Z = X/Y?

Tags: probability, statistics

If X and Y are independent exponential random variables with respective parameters λ1 and λ2, how do I find the distribution of Z = X/Y ?

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran into this problem not so long ago. Replace the variables $X_1$ with X and $X_2$ with Y and you should receive the same answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First find the domain of $Z$. Then for any $z\in D_Z$ we have
\begin{equation}
P(Z\le z) = P(X/Y\le z) = P(X\le zY) = \int_{y\in D_y}P(X\le zy)f_Y(y)dy.
\end{equation}
Solve this and differentiate with respect to $z$ to find the density function of $Z$.